# How do I calculate (age-specific) mortality rates in R?

Tags: r

Using data in the following form, in which ways can I calculate the (age-specific) mortality rate in the R programming language?

```
head(data)
##   age gender zone   Class       misc      bonus duration  death cost
## 1   0      M    1       4         12          1   0.1753      0    0
## 2   4      M    3       6          9          1   0.0000      1    0
## 3   5      F    3       3         18          1   0.4548      0    0
## 4   5      F    4       1         25          1   0.1726      0    0
## 5   6      F    2       1         26          1   0.1808      0    0
## 6   9      F    3       3          8          1   0.5425      0    0
```

That is, for each age I want to calculate the number of deaths and divide by the total number of exposed individuals in that particular age. I tried the following:

```
n <- length(data$age);
    rate <- c(1:n); 
    for (i in 1:n){
    rate[i] <- sum(subset(data, age == i)$death)/ length(subset(data, age == i))
}
```

But this was useless - obviously not all ages from 1 to n is present in the dataset - I am looking for a written program in the sense of the above which will do the job.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To get the best help with your question, please do some basic research before posting. What have you tried? The answer to this question is easily available in any R tutorial. I would start with the `aggregate()` function.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking for here. Do you simply want to know how to get conditional averages, or do you want to know about survival analysis?

Comment: @semicolon. Welcome. You may edit your question posting the code of your comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable `death` only takes on the value of zero or one, you can calculate the age-specific mortality in one line of code.

```
tapply(data$death, data$age, mean)
```

Comment: nope. the rate is deaths divided by exposure, not what you've put there.

Comment: Since each row of data corresponds to a single individual, taking the mean of `data$death` for each `data$age` does divide the number of deaths "_by the total number of exposed individuals in that particular age_", just as the original poster requested.

Comment: arg. correct you are, by that wording. The asker likely meant 'person-years of exposure', which would include the partial years lived by those that died (the definition used in demography or epidemiology) which is the answer I gave. Your answer does capture the literal question, though. Asker seems to be long gone...

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of the way there with `table()`. If we assume that all those not dying are present for 100% of the time (a year, say), and that those dying are present for 1/2 of the time, then we have enough info to calculate exposure from these data. I'm not sure what your `duration` column is, but you haven't really described the data.

```
# cheap version of your data:
DF <- data.frame(age = c(0,4,5,5,6,9), death = c(0,1,0,0,0,0))

(DAT      <- table(DF$death,DF$age))
    0 4 5 6 9
  0 1 0 2 1 1
  1 0 1 0 0 0
# weight these two rows for components of exposure:
Exposure <- colSums(DAT * c(1,.5))
# rates are the ratio of death counts in each age to exposure to risk in each age:
Rates <- DAT["1",] / Exposure
```

If you then go on to calculate a lifetable, this is the so-called `Mx` or `mx` column.